# Add some line, arc circle, and new point obtained from rotating old point in Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles

I'm new in tikz. I want to plot x-axis, y-axis, point at coordinate (4,1), line from (0,0) to (4,1), dashed line from (4,0) to (4,1) and dashed line from (0,1) to (4,1). This is  my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,-Latex, black, thick] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$X$};
        \draw[->,-Latex, black, thick] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node[above]{$Y$};
        \filldraw[black] (4,1) circle (3pt);
        \draw[black, thick, dashed] (4,0) -- (4,1);
        \draw[black, thick, dashed] (0,1) -- (4,1);
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0) -- (4,1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, from code above, I want to add some line and new point as picture below.
[image]

(a) I want add new point that obtained from rotating 45 degree from point (4,1).

(b) I want add new line from (0,0) to point (a)

(c) I want add an arc circle and text 45° (see the picture)

(d) I want add an arc circle with arrow from (4,1) to point (a)

How to make it?

Comment: Look up in the manual polar coordinates, like (45:2) instead of (1.41, 1.41). Also look for handling + and ++ . And many more.

Comment: Should the red arc follow the path of rotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code (some add to Your code):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->,-Latex, black, thick] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[right]{$X$};
        \draw[->,-Latex, black, thick] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5) node[above]{$Y$};
        \filldraw[red,rotate=45] (4,1) circle (3pt);
        \filldraw[black] (4,1) circle(3pt) ;
        \draw[black, thick, dashed] (4,0) -- (4,1);
        \draw[black, thick, dashed] (0,1) -- (4,1);
        \draw[black,thick] (0,0) -- (4,1);
        \draw[red,thick,rotate=45] (0,0) -- (4,1);
        \draw[-Latex,red,thick] (4,1) arc (atan(.25):{atan(.25)+45}:4);
        \draw[dashed] (2,.5) arc (atan(.25):{atan(.25)+45}:2) node[pos=.5,right] () {$45\circ$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```